# pandas groupby aggregate to find number of days customer made at least 1 transaction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have customer transaction dataset like this:

| ID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-21 | 5 |
| 2 | 2-1-21 | 8 |
| 1 | 2-1-21 | 6 |
| 1 | 3-1-21 | 5 |
| 2 | 3-1-21 | 9 |
| 2 | 3-1-21 | 10 |

I have to groupby and aggregate the data on customer level like this:

| ID | Total Amount | Number of days active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 3 |
| 2 | 27 | 2 |

`Total Amount` = sum of all `Amount` column

`Number of days active` = Number of days customer made 1 or more transactions

How do I calculate my column `Number of days active`? So far I have tried:

```
df= df.groupby('ID').agg({'Amount': lambda price: price.sum(),
                          'Date': lambda date: len(date).days})
```

My `Total Amount` column is fine but I cannot find the `Number of days active`

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `groupby` with `agg` : `nunique` + `sum`

```
out = df.groupby('ID').agg(Numberofdaysactive = ('Date','nunique'),TotalAmount = ('Amount','sum')).reset_index()
out
Out[384]: 
   ID  Numberofdaysactive  TotalAmount
0   1                   3           16
1   2                   2           27
```

Answer (score 1):

`nunique` should be what you need. That is, the aggregate df can be calculated by:

```
df_agg = df.groupby('ID').agg({"Amount":sum, "Date":pd.Series.nunique})
```

Note how you can pass function handles directly to `agg`.